# Webpage sizing issue

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage I'm making that consists of a centered table. It works fine when my browser is full screen, but when I make the browser smaller (or when I use a computer with less browser space, like a Mac), part of the table gets cut off, and it won't let me scroll up to see the whole table. The pictures below show how the page should look and when it's cut off.

[image: http://imgur.com/fqwURZb,JXin4Kb#0]
[image]

Here's my CSS for the table:

```
#inputTable {
    width:600px;
    height:780px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: -300px;
    margin-top: -390px;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px #06246F;
    table-layout:fixed;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: why are you using a position absolute to center it? why are you using an image service instead of creating a jsfiddle or any other code editor to display the problem?

Comment: why are you messing up with margin and position setting top:50% and then margin-top:-390px? do you really need them both?

Comment: remove your margin-top and check

Comment: I'm not a programmer. This is all stuff I've pieced together simply because it works. When I remove position absolute, the table is no longer even on the screen.  I just did whatever I could find to center the table. If there's a totally different way to do it, I'd be fine with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a mix of a few things in your css that is causing your problem (as stated by others). A solution may be to take a different approach to centering your content.

Using a container and content div with a display table and display table-cell, respectively.

```
.container
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:table;
    text-align:center;
}
.content {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

I have made [an example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6uuL/).

You can always use a max width and height for larger screens, but you need the percentage to ensure it is visible on smaller devices.

Comment: Thank you! I'm using a slight variation of this approach in order to format the webpage. Definitely works better than before.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center a div you should avoid the position absolute unless you really need it.

```
#inputTable {
    width:600px;
    height:780px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px #06246F;
    table-layout:fixed;
    overflow:auto;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 100px auto 0;
}
```

Set the margin to your needs.
Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/notme/xEa6k/).